# Is it possible to find the name of something in a csv given 2 parameters? Python

Tags: python, csv, opencsv

Say I had a csv file with 3 columns, 'name', 'price' and 'color'.

How could I go about getting the variable of the name of say, the most expensive blue item, the most expensive red, and the most expensive yellow?

Would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: try loading the file into `pandas DataFrame`. In general you should add a snippet of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our plan is to find the class we want (say, "blue" items) and, then, find the most expensive (the maximum in the `price` column).

Let's define an example DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': [a for a in "abcdef"],
        'price': [1.5, 3.8, 1.4, 5.9, 3.5, 1.9],
        'color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow']
    }).set_index('name')
```

And here our DataFrame:

```
      price   color
name               
a       1.5    blue
b       3.8     red
c       1.4  yellow
d       5.9    blue
e       3.5     red
f       1.9  yellow
```

To do the first part (find the items of a specific color), we can use Pandas' [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). So the following will select blue items and save to `blue_items`.

```py
blue_items = df[df.color == "blue"] # selects the df's slice in which df.color is equals to "blue".
```

Then we can get the index of the maximum price (as I've defined `name` to be the index column, it'll return the name):

```py
blue_items["price"].idxmax()
```

The complete code (now considering you're importing a CSV file):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", index_col="name")

most_exp_blue = df[df.color == "blue"]["price"].idxmax()  # the most expensive blue

most_exp_red = df[df.color == "red"]["price"].idxmax()  # the most expensive red

most_exp_yellow = df[df.color == "yellow"]["price"].idxmax()  # the most expensive yellow
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a life saver

Answer (score 0):

You would check each item one at a time. You would check the colour and then you would check the last most expensive price for that colour you saw. If the price is bigger you record the price and name of the new largest item. if it is not bigger you move on to the next item.

```py
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     data = csv.DictReader(csv file) 

largest = {}

for row in data:
    colour = row['colour'] 
    if largest.get(colour):
          if row['price'] > largest[colour]['price']:  # new largest price
                largest[colour]['price'] = row['price']
                largest[colour]['name'] = row['name']
    else:  # not seen before, make largest price
          largest[colour] = {}
          largest[colour]['price'] = row['price']
          largest[colour]['name'] = row['name']
```

Comment: It's not the best way, because Python isn't really fast in loops. I think it's better to rely on Pandas implementation (in C), that is much faster.

Comment: Can you share a timeit output for that? In my experience  pandas isn't going to be significantly faster for an O(n) algorithm until you've hit hundreds of thousands of entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas.  You need filter by color and sort by price

```
df[df.color == 'color2'].sort_values(by='price', ascending=False).iloc[0]
```

Here is some sample:

```
d = [dict(name = 'nm1', price=100, color='color1'),
     dict(name = 'nm2', price=200, color='color2'),
     dict(name = 'nm3', price=300, color='color3'),
     dict(name = 'nm4', price=400, color='color2')]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Dataframe example:

```
    name    price   color
0   nm1     100     color1
1   nm2     200     color2
2   nm3     300     color3
3   nm4     400
```

color2

Answer (score 0):

Example:
if your data is like this:

data={"name":['A-Blue','B-Blue','C-Blue','A-Red','B-Red','C-Red','A-Yellow','B-Yellow','C-Yellow'],
"price":[100,200,300,200,100,300,300,300,100],
"color":['Blue','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red','Yellow','Yellow','Yellow']}

then create pandas dataframe first with the below command:

pdf=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','price','color'])

Now get the index of the records with the below command:

pdf.groupby("color")["price"].idxmax()

[ remember to use argmax instead of idxmax for the pandas older versions]

Now apply PDF[] around to get the complete row of max value of each color:

pdf.iloc[pdf.groupby("color")["price"].idxmax()]

To reset the index  add reset_index to the command:
So the final answer is:

pdf.iloc[pdf.groupby("color")["price"].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)

Final output:

index name  price   color

0   C-Blue  300 Blue

1   C-Red   300 Red

2   A-Yellow    300 Yellow

( even you have duplicate higher price - first record will appear like A-yellow]

Comment: Consider using markdown markup to improve readability.